# Displaying Image in Imagebox when clicking on ListView row

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, listview

I'm having a small problem. I want to get image data to display in an Image control from my Sql table when clicking on a ListView control row. I am using C# WPF and Microsoft SQL.

Now I can already insert the image into my database but the issue that I am having is that I can't seem to retrieve the image data once I click on a row in my ListView? 
Here is the coding that I have tried...

This is the coding I use to fill the ListView:

```
    private void FillEmployeeListView()
    {
        string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        string CmdString = string.Empty;
        using (SqlConnection CON = new SqlConnection(ConString))
        {
            CmdString = "SELECT EmployeeEmailAddress, EmployeePassword, EmployeeDepartment, EmployeeIDNumber, EmployeeName, EmployeeSurname, EmployeeGender, EmployeeDOB, EmployeeHomeAddress, EmployeeTelephoneNumber, EmplyeeCity, EmployeeProvinceCode, EmployeeProfilePicture FROM Main.tblEmployeeLoginDetails";
            SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand(CmdString, CON);
            SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(CMD);
            DataTable DT = new DataTable("Main.tblEmployeeLoginIDetails");
            SDA.Fill(DT);

            lvDisplayEmployeeInformation.ItemsSource = DT.DefaultView;
        }
    }
```

My SelectionChanged Event for my ListView:

```
    private void lvDisplayEmployeeInformation_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {           
        int selectedRow = lvDisplayEmployeeInformation.SelectedIndex;

        if (selectedRow != -1)
        {
            DataView DS = (DataView)lvDisplayEmployeeInformation.ItemsSource;
            string ColumnEmailAddress = DS.Table.Rows[selectedRow].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            string ColumnPassword = DS.Table.Rows[selectedRow].ItemArray[1].ToString();
            string ColumnDepartment = DS.Table.Rows[selectedRow].ItemArray[2].ToString();
            string ColumnIDNumber = DS.Table.Rows[selectedRow].ItemArray[3].ToString();
            string ColumnName = DS.Table.Rows[selectedRow].ItemArray[4].ToString();
            string ColumnSurname = DS.Table.Rows[selectedRow].ItemArray[5].ToString();
            string ColumnGender = DS.Table.Rows[selectedRow].ItemArray[6].ToString();
            string ColumnDOB = DS.Table.Rows[selectedRow].ItemArray[7].ToString();
            string ColumnHomeAddress = DS.Table.Rows[selectedRow].ItemArray[8].ToString();
            string ColumnTelephoneNumber = DS.Table.Rows[selectedRow].ItemArray[9].ToString();
            string ColumnCity = DS.Table.Rows[selectedRow].ItemArray[10].ToString();
            string ColumnProvinceCode = DS.Table.Rows[selectedRow].ItemArray[11].ToString();
            string ColumnProfilePicture = DS.Table.Rows[selectedRow].ItemArray[12].ToString();

            txtEmailAddress.Text = ColumnEmailAddress;
            pbPassword.Password = ColumnPassword;
            txtDepartment.Text = ColumnDepartment;
            txtIDNumber.Text = ColumnIDNumber;
            txtName.Text = ColumnName;
            txtSurname.Text = ColumnSurname;
            txtGender.Text = ColumnGender;
            txtDOB.Text = ColumnDOB;
            txtHomeAddress.Text = ColumnHomeAddress;
            txtTelephoneNumber.Text = ColumnTelephoneNumber;
            txtCity.Text = ColumnCity;
            txtProvinceCode.Text = ColumnProvinceCode;
            imgProfilePicture.Source = _img;
```

And lastly this is the coding I want use to convert/insert and retrieve my image into and from my database:

```
    private void SetImage(Binary data)
    {
        if (data == null)
        {
            imgProfilePicture.BeginInit();
            imgProfilePicture.Source = null;
            imgProfilePicture.EndInit();
            return;
        }

        _img = new BitmapImage();
        _img.BeginInit();
        _img.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(data.ToArray());
        _img.EndInit();

        imgProfilePicture.BeginInit();
        imgProfilePicture.Source = _img;
        imgProfilePicture.EndInit();
    }
    private Binary GetImageBinary()
    {
        if (imgProfilePicture.Source == null)
            return null;

        Stream stream = _img.StreamSource;
        Byte[] buffer = null;
        if (stream != null && stream.CanRead && stream.Length > 0)
        {
            //Die Binary reader return 'n empty byte array :(
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
            {
                buffer = br.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
            }
        }
        return new Binary(buffer);
    }
```

I can already insert the text form the database to my textboxes once I click on a row in my listview. Any Ideas?

EDIT: The error I get is as follows - " No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found."

Comment: There could be many reasons why your images are not showing... you need to provide more information (not more code). Have you debugged your code? Does your `Binary data` variable have a value? Is the problem in the database, or in WPF?

Comment: @Sheridan Hi and thank you for the response! The thing is that it's not giving me any errors or application crashes? I don't know how to correctly display the image in the Imagebox once I click on a row in the ListView.